# SQL: Only select if minimum number of rows is met

Tags: sql

I have two tables: "Cities" and "Submissions".

I want to select a list of cities that have at least n Submissions. What is the best way to go about this? Also relevant is that most of the cities will have less than n Submissions.

I've tried selecting all the cities and then refiltering the list by doing a COUNT(*) query against submissions but this is obviously a very inefficient solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think that `COUNT` is inefficient? A Join of "Cities" and "Submissions" with a `GROUP BY Cities.Id` and `Having COUNT(*) > n` seems the best way of approaching this.

Comment: @Martin: I *think* he's suggesting that it will be too slow using a correlated subquery, i.e. - `WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Submissions WHERE Cities.id = Submissions.CityId) > n`.

Comment: Mark that's right. I have about 500 cities, which means it will be 500+1 queries.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT Cities.id
FROM Cities
JOIN Submissions ON Cities.id = Submissions.CityId
GROUP BY Cities.id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= n
```

Answer (score 4):

```
   select cityname, count(submissionid) as submissioncount
   from cities inner join submissions
   on submissions.cityid = cities.cityid
   group by cityname
   having count(submissionid) >= {yourdesiredcount}
```

Comment: Of course, if you have a common name like "Springfield" in more than one state, grouping by cityname would be insufficient. Then, you'd need to group by cityid, cityname.